# Unable to retrieve data from stash with key that contains a single quote

Tags: perl, search, catalyst

The database contains company names that have single quotes within the name.  When the user selects a company, I need to retrieve from a hash with the key=CompanyName.  Problem I'm having is not being able to retrieve the contents from Stash.

In Debug mode, I've validated the following, able to use single quotes and double quotes around the company name:

```
  DB<12> x $c->stash->{'company_list'}->{'corp_summary'}->{'Waldo\\\'s Merchandising Services, LLC'}
0  'c635|i1193|i1194|i1220|i1221|'
  DB<13> x $c->stash->{'company_list'}->{'corp_summary'}->{"Waldo\\\'s Merchandising Services, LLC"}
0  'c635|i1193|i1194|i1220|i1221|'
```

The code prints out the name I'm looking for and the replacement I've done, yet the last line of code "$codes" remains empty.

```
306       print "$cc\n";
307       print "$cc\n";
308       print "$cc\n";
309       print "$cc\n";
310       my $temp = $cc;
311       $temp =~ s/'/\/\/\/\'/g;
312       
313       print "$temp\n";
314       print "$temp\n";
315       print "$temp\n";
316       print "$temp\n";
317       print "$temp\n";
318       my $codes = $c->stash->{'company_list'}->{'corp_summary'}->{"$temp"};
```

Output from print statements:

```
Waldo's Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo's Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo's Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo's Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo///'s Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo///'s Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo///'s Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo///'s Merchandising Services, LLC
Waldo///'s Merchandising Services, LLC
```

My expected output is to have $codes to contain "c635|i1193|i1194|i1220|i1221|"

Comment: You are using forward slashes instead of backslashes and you have two more slashes than needed in `$temp`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using forward slashes instead of backslashes and you have two more slashes than needed in `$temp`. Try:

```
$temp =~ s{'}{\\'}g;
```